# Running second Lua script from within first in it's own thread/background

Tags: multithreading, lua

I am executing a `Lua` file which needs to fetch a list of campaigns and if the campaign's status is active, start dialing calls for that campaign. The problem I am facing that the dialing function takes time to fetch records from the db and slows the dialing process. So when I have 5 campaigns to run, the last campaign would have to wait until the rest of 4 are done dialing. Let's say around 2 to 3 seconds. This slows down the process.

I was thinking to modify the logic and call a new `Lua` script passing a table/arguments for campaign's data and let it run in it's own thread while quickly passing the second campaign in a loop.

How can I call another `Lua` script while not waiting for it's execution to complete and call it in the next iteration? Or should I just use some sort of multi threading / non blocking modes etc?

Comment: If you can run external lua scripts then you should be able to just run them in the background and not have to worry about them (assuming you don't need to handle error's, etc. from their running directly).

Comment: So if I run the external script, os.execute would be the best option? No I am not doing any error handling in the main script, for now.

Comment: Yes, `os.execute("./other-script.lua &")` would be the simplest way to run a second script in the background. Alternatively, use a threading library for lua or something of that sort.